# Is there a lower limit to tiny?

Tags: dnd-5e, wild-shape

From what I've read there is no lower limit to tiny in 5e. My real question is if a druid has precast alter self then wild shapes into a tiny creature can they make themselves effectively infinitely tiny until they're imperceptible

Comment: Howdy nick! I’ve closed those as a duplicate because the linked question seems to answer yours by asking what the size is of a tiny creature, which includes upper and lower limits. If you don’t think it’s a duplicate, please let us know why and what the difference is. Thank you!

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [What maximum size might a creature be, when it is smaller than Tiny?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/107428/23547)

Comment: A perfect duplicate: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/57001/ (also see linked questions).

Comment: Son Wukong, the Monkey King, could turn himself into a fly or a mosquito, and the crap he pulled off in that form should probably serve as a warning against ruling that way for a druid. ;)